# errors using JQuery encapsulation

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-7

I'm trying to use JQuery encapsulation and have created file under my js directory, **js/modules.js**

```
"use strict";

console.log("im in modules.js");

var xxModule = function() {

    console.log("im in xxModule");

    var form = $('#module-form');
    
    var processForm = function() {
        console.log("im in processForm");
    form.validate({
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            name: "please enter a valid module name"
        }
    });
    }
    return {

        processModuleForm: function() {
            console.log("im in return");
            processForm();
        },
    };
}();
```

in my php blade file, I'm calling it in the document ready function as

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/modules.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        console.log("im in ready");
        xxModule.processModuleForm();
});
</script>
```

when the page is rendered its throwing error,  **jQuery.Deferred exception: xxModule is not defined @http://dev.projects/modules/create:82:3** as below

```
im in modules.js modules.js:99:9
im in xxModule modules.js:102:11
im in ready create:81:17
jQuery.Deferred exception: xxModule is not defined @http://dev.projects/modules/create:82:3
e@https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2:30005
l/</t<@https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2:30307
setTimeout handler*l/<@https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2:30516
c@https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2:28294
fireWith@https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2:29039
fire@https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2:29075
c@https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2:28294
fireWith@https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2:29039
ready@https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2:32012
B@https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2:31791
EventListener.handleEvent*@https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2:32160
@https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2:220
@https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2:225
undefined jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2:31560
Uncaught ReferenceError: xxModule is not defined
<anonymous> http://dev.projects/modules/create:82
jQuery 13
create:82:3
```

please can you help with this issue?

thanks

Comment: Does it work if you remove `use strict`?

Comment: no, it still throws the same error

Comment: Why do you call this "jQuery encapsulation"? You're just wrapping the function in a plain JS object, nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: I got it from https://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/concepts/. sorry, I'm new to jquery/javascript trying to use "The Module Pattern" on my page.